# Verify a void method was called inside a private method with EasyMock/PowerMock

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, easymock

I have a method that looks like this (simplification)

```
private boolean x = someMethodToSetTheValueOfX();

private void method(args){
        if(x){
             method1();
        }else{
             method2();
        }
}
```

I want to write a unit test to guarantee that when x is true, method1 is called. I know I can use PowerMock's Whitebox to set the value of x and invoke the method, but how can I confirm that method1() was called? Note that method1() is void.

I am not allowed to use another framework (like Mockito) besides EasyMock/PowerMock.

Comment: Just in case: let me know if you need more information to find my answer helpful; otherwise please don't forget about accepting answers ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this wrong; that is not how you should be designing your tests.

First of all: be careful about using PowerMock... frameworks. They rely on byte code manipulation; and sooner or later that calls for trouble. The only reasonable situation to user PowerMock(ito) is when you have to test legacy production code. In any other situation: change your production code so it can be tested easily.

Then: do not test your code this way!

You use a mocking framework to create/control those objects that you pass to your "class under test". You don't use the framework to directly test your "class under test"! More specifically: you don't want to write test code that knows about private methods - those are implementation details.

What you do instead:

a) as said, you can use mocking to pass objects into your class under test. And then you can control/verify those mocks see the calls that you expect your "class under test" to make. So, worst case, you could put method1/2 on a different object; and then you can use mock/verify to check if they were called as expected.

b) you create objects of your "class under test" ... and then "assert" on the properties of those objects; or on results that method calls return.

Comment: Also not that by using PowerMock you are changing the unit under test. So you aren't actually testing your class under test, but something that won't be seen in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use:

```
System.out.println("method one was called");
```

If you can print to a consol in an IDE like eclipse, or use:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue(null, "method one was called");
```

And put them inside method1

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It's about unit testing (like, JUnit tests). Not about troubleshooting. But otherwise yes, I'd do the first one :)